# How to preserve file mode attributes with cygwin cp command on Windows 10?

Tags: cygwin, cp

The same cygwin version 1.5.25 is installed on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

With a perl script using the stat command, I see the source file mode is 666.

The source file is a simple text file.

After doing a `cp` to copy the file into another folder, the mode of the target file stays at 666 on Windows 7 but becomes 444 on Windows 10.

Using either `-p` or `--preserve=mode` doesn't seem to change the outcome of the `cp` operation on Windows 10.

Is there a way to preserve the mode attributes such that the target file doesn't become read-only on Windows 10?

The version of `cp` retrieved with `cp --version` is 6.10 and it is at C:\cygwin\bin\cp.exe.

Comment: and `--preserve=all` ?

Comment: The `--preserve=all` doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Initially I thought it was related to the version of `cp` I was using from the coreutils package.

The older package from cygwin 1.5.25 is using coreutils 6.10
But after doing some more testing, it appears to be related to a Windows10 folder setting that I am missing.

If I change the security property of the folder to add the Everyone group, with the Read&Execute permissions, all seem good.

I will focus now on the folder settings to make sure I have a proper solution.